# How can I use a back-reference in place of a filename in sed?

Tags: sed, latex

I am trying to use `sed` to scan through a file and find a pattern, then use part of the matched pattern as a filename and insert the contents of the file at that location. I can get most of it to work, but I can't seem to figure out how to use a back-reference in place of the filename.

The short version is that a need to pre-process a latex file and get rid of all the top level `\input` commands becauase `lilypond-book` is Stupid™.

```
# Setup files for example
$ echo "foo\n\\input{file2}\nfoo" > file1
$ echo "bar\nbar" > file2

# Use sed to find and replace latex \input commands
$ sed $'/^\\\\input{\\(.*\\)}$/ {r file2\n d}' file1
foo
bar
bar
foo
```

So far so good, but that has a hard coded file name and I need to use the result of the group match above (the part between the `{` and `}` delimiters) as the file name. Unfortunately this does not work:

```
$ sed $'/^\\\\input{\\(.*\\)}$/ {r \\1\n d}' file1
foo
foo
```

How can I use the matched pattern as the file name in a scenario like this?

Comment: The real answer is of course awk.

Comment: @Gilles I had a hunch that might be the case, but A) my awk skills are nothing to gawk at and B) I already have a whole bunch of sed processing going on so this is easy to work into the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed` you could do something like:

```
sed '/^\\input{\(.*\)}$/{s//\1/;s/'\''/&\\&&/g;s/.*/cat<'"'&'/e}"
```

(that is build a `cat<'the-file'` command (escaping the quotes in the file name if needed) and use the `e` flag of the `s` command (which is GNU specific) to evaluate that command).

Comment: Thanks, and this does get the job done. Yet it also works without the `s/'\''/&\\&&/g;` bit  at all, which makes me wonder what issues you are anticipating that my MWE does not turn up. What does that bit do?

Comment: Or even `sed 's/^[\]input{\([^}]*\)}$/cat \"\1\"/e' file1` maybe?

Comment: @Caleb, that's [to take into account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) input like `\input{Caleb's file}`. Or `\input{'x;rm -rf /;'}`